# Cannot connect AWS EC2 NodeRed to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, node-red

Guys I have deployed my NodeRed in ubuntu EC2 and also create a RDS MySQL,**In locally everything is fine** but when i try to connect the node mysql with my RDS on AWS cloud it show an error
**"ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR"**. Do i need some configulation? I have also try to set inbound and outbound rules to all traffic but it still not work.

**For more infomation:**

1. I have deployed my NodeJS  app in the same EC2 server that nodered has deployed,it can connect with the same RDS perfectly.
2. In Nodered flow it has node mqtt that seems cannot conenct with mqtt broker too.(in locally,it  can connect normally).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem now by adding a new user of My RDS Mysql, instead of using root, and changing the credential with new user and it's working! But I still dont know the root problem yet. If anyone knows, please tell me.

Comment: Most likely the root user only had permission to connect to the database from `localhost`

Comment: `root` is a reserved user on RDS. You don't have `root` access to RDS.